# Is there a way to prepare git tag messages?

Tags: git, git-tag

When adding a new tag in git, I would like to automatically modify the default (empty) tag message before my $EDITOR fires up—similar to the way that git allows to prepare commit messages via the `prepare-commit-msg` hook.

For example:

```
git tag -s v1.2.3
```

should open my editor with pre-filled contents like this:

```
Release v1.2.3:

  * Dynamically generated message 1

  * Dynamically generated message 2

Default standard text.

#
# Write a tag message
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored
```

Is there any way to achieve this?  Unfortunately, the `prepare-commit-msg` hook doesn’t work with tag messages.  (Either this, or I was too dumb to find out how to do it.)

Comment: Note: With Git 2.17 (Q2 2018), there is also an `--edit` option to `git tag` now. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49215146/6309

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an alias which would first populate a temp file with the desired content and then run `git tag` with the option `-F <file>`/`--file=<file>` to feed the temp file's content into the tag message. Theoretically, something like this:

```
[alias]
    tag-prepare = !~/bin/prepare_file.sh && git tag --file="/home/user/temp/temp.txt"
```

You would then call it with `git tag-prepare v1.2.3`.

Note that the `prepare_file.sh` script needs to create the entire tag message because the `--file` option does not open the editor to edit the content anymore, it only takes w/e is in the provided file and uses that as the message.

Comment: I already thought about a command line solution using the `-F` parameter, but I still want to be able to modify the message in my editor.  The automatically generated message fits entirely most of the time, but not always.

Comment: Well, you can do it through the script. In the script, open the file with $EDITOR with the text already generated, edit it, save it, exit, let the script finish and then execute `git tag` with the `-F` option.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
message="A header line

A body line...
Other lines...

Final line...
"
git tag --annotate --message "${message}" --edit 0.8.0
```

It will start tag creation and opens an editor. In my case `vim`:
[image]